# Syncing thunderbird configuration via git

Tags: git, synchronization, thunderbird

I have all my configurations in git, which helps me to sync my entire environment among multiple machines. I'd like to do the same with Mozilla Thunderbird configuration. The problem is that there is a lot of data in it's config folder and I doubt that everything is needed (there is IMAP cache, etc.).

My config folder looks like this:

```
times.json
..
secmod.db
mailViews.dat
blist.sqlite
ImapMail
signons.sqlite
abook.mab
Mail
search.json
search-metadata.json
google_tasks_sync
formhistory.sqlite
mimeTypes.rdf
simple_storage.sqlite
webappsstore.sqlite
extensions
extensions.sqlite
extensions.ini
storage.sdb
compatibility.ini
content-prefs.sqlite
places.sqlite
pluginreg.dat
history.mab
addons.sqlite
blocklist.xml
calendar-data
downloads.sqlite
.parentlock
permissions.sqlite
localstore.rdf
session.json
folderTree.json
global-messages-db.sqlite
cookies.sqlite
key3.db
cert8.db
virtualFolders.dat
panacea.dat
prefs.js
.
```

Which of this files should I include in my git repo (e.g. how should my .gitignore look like)? Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Good question; I think it should be migrated to superuser, though.

Comment: you should definitely look for a better way. sqlite are binary blobs in git ...